# Connection Management in UDP with C++

Tags: c++, sockets, session, boost-asio, udpclient

I have a client/Server systems implemented by Boost asio in C++ that a client sends a request to server. Then the server registers this client to the list of alive clients and keeps sending data to it over UDP protocol. But, the server should keep track of alive clients and stop sending data to a disconnected or dead client.

I wonder how I can implement the UDP session/socket management here since UDP is a connectionless protocol and cannot provide us any information about alive clients. Should I use another library for UDP session management in C++? Or I should use another protocol in the application layer for UDP session management.

I know there is a library in Java called Verax IPMI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verax_IPMI which provides this ability. But, how about in C++?

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a list of endpoints that you've seen recently (meaning they sent you a datagram). Usually, you allow for a grace time (e.g. 30s) before removing a client from the list.

That way, if some datagrams were dropped you don't immediately forget the "connection".

Comment: Would you please clarify your solution to me? I cannot understand it exactly.